# Using Fragment and AppCompatActivity classes together

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, appcompatactivity

Hi I'm trying to make an app which uses two different classes I'm aware I can't use extend with two classes in Java. How would I go about separating the below code into two different classes so one can extend Fragment and the other AppCompatActivity?

```
package com.example.oliver.myapplication;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MyFragment extends AppCompatActivity, Fragment {

    Button b, b2;
    MediaPlayer nice, burp;
    ImageButton img;
    int n;
    MediaPlayer [] s = new MediaPlayer[6];
    AlertDialog.Builder adb;

    public static MyFragment newInstance() {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
            img = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);

            s[0] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.burp);
            s[1] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.robert);
            s[2] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.burp2);



        img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    Random r = new Random();
                    n = r.nextInt(3);

                    s[n].start();
                }
            }
        });return rootView;


}}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of extending an Activity and Fragment? They are separated constructs in Android. Exactly what functionality are you trying to combine by trying to draw from both of those parents?

Comment: I want to be able to swipe navigate the App and the app uses MediaPlayer to play sound

Comment: Implementing Swipe Navigation: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Answer (score 5):

The above code is not valid Java.

A class can only extend one class. You activity/fragment is extending 2 classes at the same time.

The class given above is a valid Fragment subclass, except for these lines :

```
        s[0] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.burp);
        s[1] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.robert);
        s[2] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.burp2);
```

Replace "MyFragment.this" with "MyFragment.getActivity()".

Now you can replace "extends AppCompatActivity, Fragment" with "extends Fragment"

Now you have a valid Fragment.

Create the AppCompatActivity yourself. Look up how you can add a fragment to an activity.

As a tip in good programming practice, I suggested that you move the following code in onCreateView() to onActivityCreated() :

```
        img = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        s[0] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.burp);
        s[1] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.robert);
        s[2] = MediaPlayer.create(MyFragment.this, R.raw.burp2);



    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                Random r = new Random();
                n = r.nextInt(3);

                s[n].start(); 
            } 
        } 
    });
```

Change

```
        img = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img);
```

to

```
        img = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.img);
```